Onsen-ui, button with icon and text
Hi I'am trying go get to grips with Onsen-ui but I am struggling how to solve the following problem.
I want to add a button to the toolbar.  I want to increase the size of the icon but what I find is the text to go with the button does not centre itself vertically with the icon.


 <ons-toolbar-button>
      <ons-icon
    icon="md-chevron-right"
    size="80px, material:24px">
  </ons-icon>
      Button
      </ons-toolbar-button>



Can anyone show me how I can centre the text vertically.
Thanks in advance.
